# temp file not getting placed in sub directory

Tags: php

Been trying to figure out why my `$temp` file will not get placed in the `$un` directory. The directory structure gets created but the temp file is not moved there. To verify a temp file is being created - if I remove the `mkdir()` the temp file is added to `uploads` `folder`. How come the file is not being created in sub directory?

`uploads/subfolder/`

```
$temp = 'uploads/'.mkdir('uploads/'.$un) . md5($_FILES['image']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $temp)) {
// do something here..
}
```

Comment: `mkdir` returns bool value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this,

```
  mkdir('uploads/'.$un);
  $temp = "uploads/$un/" . md5($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Answer (score 3):

As function `mkdir` returns bool value, this line

```
$temp = 'uploads/'.mkdir('uploads/'.$un) . md5($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

is evaluated to

```
$temp = 'uploads/' . ('1' or '') . 'md5-filename';
```

So as you can see - your `$temp` path will never store your `$un` subdirectory.

The solution can be:

```
$temp = 'uploads/' . $un;
$res = mkdir($temp);
// check that folder created successfully
if ($res) {    
    $temp .= md5($_FILES['image']['name']);
    // upload your file
}
```

Comment: Thanks, totally makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: May be I could be wrong, there should be `/` after $un, to separate file name and folder